# Payments on website: From customers to the website and vice versa

Tags: django, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, banking

I am creating a website that needs to do this points:

1. Receive payments to the Web site.
   I know that there are several payments gateways to do this. Can anyone recommend any?
2. Make payments from the Web site to the people who are registered on the site. This people can live in any country and so they can have accounts in any bank of the world.
   It's possible to make bank transfers to any bank?
   There's another way to do it, for example with PayPal?
   If anyone has another idea how to do this I would be very grateful if you tell me. Without having this resolved I cannot move forward on my website.
   My Web site uses: HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, Jquery, Django y Python, with a SQLLite database.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With PayPal you can:

- Receive money using PayPal Checkout. Make two routes on the server, one for 'Create Order' and  one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Pair the two routes with this payer approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
- Trigger sending money from your account to any email address using Payouts. Apply for that here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts .  If the email does not already have a PayPal account associated, they'll get a message asking them to create one to claim the payment. If they don't, it will be automatically refunded after 30 days.

Comment: Thanks Preston PHX, you have helped me a lot. I will read the documentation that you have sent me.